# how can i output this format from retrieving my code from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

The format should be as followed, an array of user names and in each user name the hotel name from the hotels table with its corresponding ratings, which could be extracted from the rating table. However, i would need to join the users table in order to link an order list to extract the user name from it.

Rating list code

```
                     $books =  array(

                "phil" => array("Sandman"=> 2.5, "Jurys Inn Newcastle" => 
                      3.5,
                                "Premier Inn Newcastle" => 3, "Sunderland 
           Marrtiot" => 4,
                                "Travelodge Sunderland" => 2.5,
                                "StayBridge Suits London" => 3.5),

                "sameer" => array("Apex London Wall" => 2.5, "Jurys Inn Newcastle" => 3.5,
                                  "Mercure Leeds parkaway wilds" => 3, "Sunderland Marrtiot" => 3.5,
                                  "Travelodge Sunderland" => 2.5, "StayBridge Suits London" => 1),

                "john" => array("Linthwaite House" => 5, "Britannia Hotel leeds" => 3.5,
                                "Premier Inn Newcastle" => 1),

                "peter" => array("chaos" => 5, "php in action" => 3.5),

                "jill" => array("Apex London Wall" => 1.5, "Britannia Hotel leeds" => 2.5,
                                "Mercure Leeds parkaway wilds" => 4, "the host: a novel" => 3.5,
                                "the world without end" => 2.5, "StayBridge Suits London" => 3.5),

                "bruce" => array("Apex London Wall" => 3, "the hollow" => 1.5,
                                 "Mercure Leeds parkaway wilds" => 3, "Sunderland Marrtiot" => 3.5,
                                 "the appeal" => 2, "StayBridge Suits London" => 3),

                "tom" => array("chaos" => 2.5)


            );
```

My tables in the phpmyadminl
tbl_rating table (id,rate,user_id and hote_id)
hotel table (id,hotel_name,hotel_price,image,description) 
users table (id,name,email and password)

The reason why I included three tables is that i want to join the tables in order to extract the name from the users table, and the hotel_name from the hotel table with the rating table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$usersHotels = getUsersHotels();
function getUsersHotels()
{
   //mysqli provider - you can use any your own db connection
   $mysqli = getDbConnection();

   $query = 'SELECT  users_table.name as user_name, hotel_table.hotel_name, 
   tbl_rating.rate FROM users_table JOIN tbl_rating ON 
   (users_table.id=tbl_rating.user_id) JOIN hotel_table ON (hotel_table.id = 
   tbl_rating.hote_id)';

   $data = array();
   if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         if(isset($data[$row['user_name']) && is_array( $data[$row['user_name']])){
           $data[$row['user_name']] = array_merge( $data[$row['user_name']], array($row['hotel_name'] => $row['rate']));
         } else  {
           $data[$row['user_name']] = array($row['hotel_name'] => $row['rate']);
         }
      }
   }
   $result->free();
   return $data;
}

//optional code.
function getDbConnection()
{
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "world");

   /* check connection */
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
       printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
      exit();
   }
   return $mysqli;
}
```